# Refresh outputscreen and take inputs at the same time in java

Tags: java

Hi I'm about to write a programm which starts multiple minecraft servers:
If you type 'start servername', it starts this server.
If you type 'watch servername', the program shows the output of this server and you should be able to send commands (to this server) at the same time until you type sth. like 'exit'. The problem is that I don't know how to refresh the outputscreen and take the inputs from the keyboard at the same time.
Here is my code from the server class:

```
class Server{
private String name;
private StartCommand command;
private boolean on = false;
private Process p = null;

public Server(StartCommand c, String name){
    this.command = c;
    this.name = name;
}

public void start(){
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.getCommand());
        System.out.println("Server: " + name + " is on now!");
        on = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        on = false;
    }
}

public void watch(){
    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
        on = false;
    }
}
}
```

I hope you can help me.
Greetings,
Fabian

Comment: do you plan to make a GUI-application or a command line/terminal application ?

Comment: no just simple  a command line app

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, your application will monitor many servers, read all their responses and post them to the same screen. Am I right?

Comment: that's correct (but you can monitor just one server at a time)! If you want to see some of the other classes just ask.

Comment: Implement two threads. One - to read user's input from `System.in` and send commands to the current active server. Another - to read server's response and print it to `System.out`.

Comment: can you give me a quick example. i think i still have the problem that i am not able to rum them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Server console should be displayed in separate terminal and client console where user can type  in the command. 
Similar to any server like mysql has a log where server output's are displayed. mysql client command where user type in their sql commands.
Or else redirect watch output to a file and then type the next command.